# Freebsd: invalid ipv4 address 

Tags: networking, installation, freebsd

params are:

ip: 94.23.147.56
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast 94.23.147.56
gw: 176.31.248.254

what's wrong in here? this params works perfectly with debian.. it's not my fault that stupid ovh.co.uk who knows nothing about networking uses this insane params.. but why fsbd dares to validate them... how to setup network in that installation wizard???

**Update**

I already setuped network, it works with stated configuration. My question was how to enter this configuration to sysinstall utility or atleast how to enable it through holographic shell.

Comment: Your assigned address is in a /32 subnet, and the gateway (which, by definition, must be in the same subnet as the host - this is impossible in a /32) is nowhere near that subnet?  I wouldn't validate it either if I were FreeBSD.  Where did you get this IP information?

Comment: Not only that - the broadcast address is the same as the ip. That's not very likely to be correct as well.

Comment: This is OVH hosting configuration, it works on debian and this stated in their guide http://help.ovh.ie/Bridgeclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake it — use wider mask (for e. g., /30 or /29) and choose an IP inside of that sub-network to be your router. Add static arp entry for that IP with MAC address of real gateway. I think it should work then.

**Updated**: Minimal network would fit is /28: `94.23.147.48/28`. `94.23.147.49` can be chosen as default gateway then. Placing ARP entry for it:

`arp -s 94.23.147.49 MAC:ADDR:OF:176.31.248.254`

— now `94.23.147.49` can be used as default router.

Comment: any examples please? I'm not so skillful =)

Comment: @holms, added. It's really simple

Answer (score 1):

How would the host reach the gateway? It's not directly connected to it, and has no route to it. This is a nonsensical configuration.

The configuration page you linked to just has a mistake in it. They used the subnet mask for a failover IP in place of the subnet mask for the primary IP. The subnet mask for the primary IP must be the correct subnet mask for the subnet. And the gateway *must* be in the same subnet as the primary IP.

Comment: It sounds like the correct netmask is `255.255.255.0`, and the correct gateway in your case is `94.23.147.254`.

Comment: this doesn't work. I already setuped network, it works with stated configuration. My question was how to enter this configuration to sysinstall utility or atleast how to enable it through holographic shell..

Answer (score 0):

The netmask 255.255.255.255 is invalid as it is saying that the entire address is the subnet part. You would need to contact your provider and determin the correct netmask setting. 255.255.255.0 is common.

Comment: as I stated in comment earlier, this works in DEBIAN. here's params from that hosting http://help.ovh.ie/Bridgeclient you can see there's the whole config for freebsd but how to enter this to INSTALL CD?

Comment: # `ifconfig em0 inet IP.Fail.over netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast IP.Fail.over`
    # `route add -net Your.Server.IP.254/32 IP.Fail.over`
    # `route add default Your.Server.IP.254`

ifconfig_* variables just contains parameters passed to `ifconfig`, route_* - to `route add`